# Adding facebook user to my jabber roster

Tags: javascript, facebook, strophe

I have chat build on strophe. When I try to invite my facebook xmpp username I got this on my server:

```
Trying to open s2s connection: pregmatch.org -> chat.facebook.com with TLS=true 
s2s connection: pregmatch.org -> chat.facebook.com (remote server not found)
Reconnect delay expired: Will now retry to connect to chat.facebook.com when needed.
```

If facebook support xmpp, this is stupid if you can not invite some user, or they can not invite you (no metter if you have facebook account or not)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XMPP world, apart from client-server architecture upon which Jabber/XMPP communication is based there is another aspect called "federation", i.e., the ability for two XMPP servers in different domains to exchange XML stanzas. Unfortunately facebook doesn't support federation. Google Talk servers do. As of result you won't be able to add or interact with facebook jabber id's

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nice and simple.

Comment: @Abhinav Singh: Can you explain how can I connect with google talk xmpp federation? I have an application works with xmpp, and I want to connect to gTalk. thanx

Comment: You dont need anything specific to enable connection with google talk servers. Just point your xmpp client to `talk.google.com:5222` and that should be enough. However, if you are running your own jabber server, you must enable your server to listen on s2s port `(default: 5269)`. Read through http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0220.html and http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0238.html for some more intricate details

Comment: I can confirm this. Also, if I add a non-Facebook user to my Facebook XMPP roster, once I try to communicate with that user, Facebook instantly disconnects me.